# Appsflyer Universal Links iOS not routing to requested page

Tags: cordova, ios-universal-links, appsflyer

Following the setup for the appsflyer cordova plugin as well as enabling universal links for iOS (following Appsflyer documentation) does not result in actually directing a user to a specific page in our app.

**Versions:**

```
cordova 7.1.0
cordova-android 6.4.0
cordova-ios 4.5.3
cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk 4.3.0
iOS: 10.3.3
```

The associated domains is set to `applinks:<_onelink_id>.onelink.me` for the Xcode project. Then, we publish a onelink with a deep link into a specific page in our app (with a query param such as `af_dp=<custom_scheme>://some/specific/route`)

On Android, the normal deeplinks work. E.g: `handleOpenUrl` is called, then we call `appsflyer.handleOpenUrl` and then we continue to route into the app to the page requested in the deeplink.

However, on iOS it does open our app when it is installed but `handleOpenUrl` is never called. I cannot find any other part mentioning a different handling of universal links in the documentation.

As the app is opened, universal links must be configured correctly. How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has a separate method of handling Universal Links (in general, and also in AppsFlyers Cordova Plugin):

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler
{
    [[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the relevant code in AppsFlyer's Cordova plugin: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/blob/master/src/ios/AppsFlyerPlugin.m#L420

In AppsFlyer's Cordova plugin, the expected data should be returned in the success callback of `initSdk` , provided that onInstallConversionDataListener data is set to true, for example:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
     alert(result); 
     // will return success for init, and also ConversionData and onAppOpenAttribution Data 
};

function onError(err) {
    // handle error
}

var options = {
               devKey:  'd3Ac9qPardVYZxfWmCspwL',
               appId: '123456789',
               onInstallConversionDataListener: true
             };

window.plugins.appsFlyer.initSdk(options, onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. initSdk and install attribution work perfectly. I already saw the handler for UL's in the iOS sources.

If I understand you correctly, the `af_dp` parameters passed through the onelink will be returned when `initSdk` succeeds? I could not find this in the documentation

Comment: It will indeed be returned in under `data.link` in the JSON parsed from `result` in the success callback. Thanks